# How to sorting items into ArrayList on Android

Tags: android, list, kotlin, arraylist

In my application I want add some items into my `ArrayList`.
But I should added this items with **orders**!
**Order 1** in **item[0]**, **order 2** in **item[1]**, **order 3** in **item[2]** and more ...

I want when **group** equals **child**, and then added this items with **order** in my `ArrayList`

**I receive this JSON from server :**

```
"questions": [
                {
                    "question": {
                        "id": 142373470,
                        "body": "Title",
                        "group": "child",
                        "order": 2,
                    },
                    "answer": {
                        "id": 1012696380,
                        "body": "Answer",
                    }
                },
                {
                    "question": {
                        "id": 1358430715,
                        "body": "Title",
                        "group": "slave",
                        "order": 1,
                    },
                    "answer": {
                        "id": 1000492257,
                        "body": "Answer",
                    }
                }
                    "question": {
                        "id": 1000492257,
                        "body": "Title",
                        "group": "slave",
                        "order": 3,
                    },
                    "answer": {
                        "id": 357947093,
                        "body": "Answer",
                    }
                },
                {
                    "question": {
                        "id": 2082411987,
                        "body": "Title",
                        "group": "child",
                        "order": 1,
                    },
                    "answer": {
                        "id": 1644143793,
                        "body": "Answer",
                    }
                },
                {
                    "question": {
                        "id": 1155092697,
                        "body": "Title",
                        "group": "child",
                        "order": 3,
                    },
                    "answer": {
                        "id": 1988774446,
                        "body": "Answer",
                    }
                }
            ]
```

I write below codes, but just add items when **group** equals **child**! but I want added to `ArrayList` when **group** equals **child** and with **order**!

**My codes:**

```
for (element in data.results.questionAnswers) {
            if (element.question.group == CHILD) {
                myQuestionAnswers.add(element)
            }
}
```

I write above codes, but just added items when group equals child! but I want added this items this orders field!

**Order** is one of **question's** field!

How can I it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data.results.questionAnswers.filter{ it.question.group == CHILD }
   .sortedBy{ it.question.order }
```

See [filter](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html) and [sortedBy](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-by.html) for more information